# How do I write a datatrigger to change the value of a dependency property based on a change of a second dependency property?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, triggers

I want to change the state of a dependency property (Mode) in a UserControl triggered off of a change change of a second dependency property (ViewType).

I tried defining a DataTrigger as follows, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControls:MyUserControl}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Value="ViewType2">
                <Setter Property="Mode" Value="Logon"/>
            </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

To verify that my binding was working correctly I wrote the following test XAML in the same user control:

```
    <Style x:Key="butstyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Value="ViewType2">
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

When I assigned this style to a button, I see the foreground color change to white at the right time, which proves my Binding to ViewType is working.

I seems I need to use a style under usercontrol.resources (like in the first block of code above), but the "Mode" property is never set.

Is this the right way to do this? I'd like to try to keep this in XAML if possible, but I'm not comfortable how triggers should work when they are not related directly to visual elements.

In case its relevant, the "ViewType" bound property is defined in a parent UserControl, and the "Mode" property is defined on MyUserControl.

**Update:**

I used a converter to find out that my trigger is being called, however my setter is not getting engaged for some reason. Here is the code for my DP which I am trying to set. Breakpoints on neitehr the set() nor the OnModeChanged() are called. Is there anything wrong with my Dependency Property?

```
    public enum ModeStates { Logon, NextState }

    public ModeStates Mode
    {
        get { return (ModeStates)GetValue(ModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModeProperty, value); }
    }

    protected static readonly DependencyProperty ModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Mode", typeof(ModeStates), typeof(MyUserControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnModeChanged))
            );


    private static void OnModeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

            // .......

    }
```

**Update:**

I was able to use DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged() to solve my problem in a pretty clean fashion.

Comment: This is comment and not an aswer as I have not tested it.  You might be able to do this with a converter.  Is there a reason you cannot just do this in the object you are binding to?

Comment: how to use DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged() to solve your problem ? Could you provide some code please ?

Comment: Sorry, this post was from many years ago and I have long stopped working on this language and framework, nor do I remember the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the dependency properties in question are defined on the UserControl you need to set it's style property, not add a default style inside the resources.

to set the style inline in XAML

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControls:MyUserControl}">
      <!-- Triggers -- >
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Adam. I was under the impression that any Style with a target type and no name would automatically be assigned to all targets that match, so I don't see why your method would be any different. However I tried it anyway, but still get the same result (the setter is never called). Any more ideas? I added a sentence of clarification to the original post about the DPs ("In case its relevant, the "ViewType" bound property is defined in a parent UserControl, and the "Mode" property is defined on MyUserControl.")

Comment: it would be helpful if you provided the control heirachy. You are correct about a default style (no key only, targettype) however it will be applied to all children of the UserControl it is defined in. If this usercontrol is the same as the one you are trying to effect in the triggers it won't be used (as it is not a child of itself)

Comment: I checked the output window, no binding errors there. Since it still doesn't work even when defining the style specifically as you mention, I don't think the control hierarchy is related the problem, though the usercontrol is the same one where I am trying to effect the triggers.

Comment: @Locksleyu What Adam says is correct. The style is not being applied because it's scope is "all children inside the UserControl", and that doesn't include the UserControl itself. His syntax would make the style apply to the UserControl itself, **if** the `Mode` property is not explicitly set on the UserControl. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx for more details. I have also occasionally encountered an issue where I need to set a default setter in the style in order for triggered setters to work, so you could give that a try.

Comment: I found out that my trigger is being triggered (or at least an associated converter is being called), but for some reason the DP setting isn't working so I added more information to the original post about the DP I am trying to set.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810557/how-do-i-write-a-datatrigger-to-change-the-value-of-a-dependency-property-based/7810714#7810714), are you setting the `Mode` property in the `<UserControl>` tag anywhere? If you do, it is overwriting the triggered value.

Also, on occasion I have had issues with a triggered value not getting set unless a default value is also defined in the style.

For example, sometimes this will not work

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControls:MyUserControl}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Value="ViewType2">
                <Setter Property="Mode" Value="Logon"/>
            </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

while this does

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControls:MyUserControl}">
        <Setter Property="Mode" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Value="ViewType2">
                <Setter Property="Mode" Value="Logon"/>
            </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas Rachel. I don't have any places in the UserControl's XAML where I am setting the Mode property, but there are several places in the code behind where I am setting it (based on other events such as button presses, etc.). I hope this isn't a problem because the value of Mode is based on several different conditions. Probably a slightly better name for it would be 'state' as it reflects the state of the control at any point in time.

Comment: @Locksleyu If you define a property explicitly on the object, either in XAML or Code-Behind, it will overwrite any styled or triggered values. One alternative is to set the value in the Style, such as with a binding, because then the Triggered value is allowed to overwrite it. See the following link for more information about of the order in which DependencyProperties are applied: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Comment: Rachel, by "define a property explicitly on the object" are you referring to setting the value (i.e. Mode=NextState; in code), or are you referring to creating the dependency property itself? I am creating a custom dependency property in the code via  DependencyProperty.Register(), does this mean that I can't safely set that DP via a datatrigger/setter?

Comment: @Locksleyu Sorry for the confusion, I mean setting the value in code such as `Mode=NextState`

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I made an answer post with an update (it ended up above this one for some reason), check it out if you get a chance.

Comment: @Locksleyu If you do an update, edit your Original Question instead of adding it as an Answer. Also, if you're solution leads you to asking a question completely different than you're original question, it is a good idea to accept an answer to your original question, and then post a new question.